# WebTestClient throws Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-refused, webtestclient

Our integration tests in Spring Boot 3.2.0 via `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and `WebTestClient` fail with the following exception

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException:
Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80
```

The test looks as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    protected WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void testShiftLog() {

        // Given
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(URI.create(SHIFTLOG_ENDPOINT_URL))
                .build().toUri();

        ShiftLogItem body = generateSchichtbuchItem();

        // When, Then
        webTestClient.post().uri(uri)
                .body(Mono.just(body), ShiftLogItem.class)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .exchange() // HERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN.
                .expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectBody(Void.class);
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I can see that the `WebTestClient` object is configured correctly, namely to the random port. Still, the execption refers to *localhost:80* what is totally odd. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: So the question is why `WebTestClient` is trying to connect at port 80 instead of at the random port selected by `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: In the first place why the test fails and yes, why under the hood it throws such an exception with such an odd message.

Comment: Let me back up, then.  The exception message reports the issue as being unable to connect to port 80 on the local machine's loopback interface.  That's a natural default location for the client to try to connect to, but you have configured with `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`, which makes it highly unlikely that port 80 is the correct one for the web environment under test.  I don't find that message particularly odd, but I don't know enough about this test framework to tell you exactly what is wrong with your test.

Comment: It is odd because the object `webTestClient` is actually configured to that random port correctly so why is it still trying to use 80?

Comment: ... and I started by asking whether *exactly* that point was what you are asking about.  Is that indeed it, or is there more?  Because everything else I can see here follows from that.

Comment: Try adding @AutoConfigureWebTestClient annotation in your test class?

Comment: @nmina, this is for a Mock Environment but not for tests with a running server: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-mock-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now. The issue here is the `.uri(URI uri)` part. If you have a base URI applied as here then the `.uri(URI uri)` will not be applied to the base URI but takes its place instead.

So in order to fix it you must use the overloaded `.uri(String uri)` method. You can do it easily by URI's `toString()` method:

```
// When, Then
webTestClient.post().uri(uri.toString())...
```

See also the Spring Java Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.UriSpec.html#uri(java.net.URI)